# Priority Exception in try catch C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have this code:

```
try {
        var bookingResult = externalService.Confirm(masterLocator, itemLocator);
    }
catch (AvailabilityException)
{
        ConfirmingService.SaveErrorType(itemLocator.Id,(int)ErrorType.Availability);
        throw;
}
catch
{
        ConfirmingService.MarkItem(confirmation.Id);
        throw;
}
```

When I execute the program, I know that the exception is an Availability Exception because I forced the service to give me the Availability Exception, but always enters the empty catch.

What am I doing wrong? or Why always enter in the catch empty?

Comment: Because it's not an AvailailtyException?

Comment: What do you mean by "in change always enter"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: To help debug, do not use the empty catch, use `catch (Exception ex)` instead. Then you can put a breakpoint in the catch block and see what the exception type really is.

Comment: Try breaking in the catch to be 100% sure AvailabilityException is the type getting thrown

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I forced the service to give me the Availabity Exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet I try to explain that always enters the catch empty, although I received an AvailabilityException.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question: do you have _two_ `AvailabilityException` classes defined? One in your `externalService` assembly and another in the `try/catch` assembly?

Comment: If the empty catch is being reached, you obviously are encountering a different Exception type. Add an exception variable declaration and put a breakpoint on your MarkItem statement.

Comment: Use the debugger. You're probably getting a `SoapException<AvailabilityException>` or something like that.

Comment: Or a `NullReferenceException` because `externalService` never got defined.

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was that the Service sent me two different AvailabilityException.

Very useful your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Service sent me two different AvailabilityException.

Now I catch the different AvailabilityException.

Very useful your comments